# Невозможно обработать повисшую символьную ссылку

Tags: php, ubuntu

Поставил phpmyadmin.

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

Выдает chmod: невозможно обработать повисшую символьную ссылку «/var/www/phpmyadmin».

Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Операция по изменению прав над самими символическими ссылками не допускаются. Надо выполнить chmod над тем файлом или папкой, на которую ссылка собственно и ссылается. То есть в вашем случае

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

так наверное будет правильнее

Comment: Нет. Мы поместили ссылку на пхпадмин в папку WWW. теперь нам надо изменить права на эту ссылку чтоб работать с пхпадмином.